# Cisco BGP Route Not Appearing in Route Table

Tags: routing, cisco-ios

I have added a few prefixes (called allnet) into BGP route table. The prefixes include the following;

```
ip prefix-list allnet seq 460 permit 10.69.118.0/23
ip prefix-list allnet seq 465 permit 10.69.108.0/22
ip prefix-list allnet seq 470 permit 10.69.108.0/24
ip prefix-list allnet seq 475 permit 10.69.109.0/24
ip prefix-list allnet seq 480 permit 10.69.110.0/24
ip prefix-list allnet seq 485 permit 10.69.111.0/24
```

However, when I look for the prefixes in BGP withe the following command:

`show ip bgp prefix-list allnet | inc 10.69.` None of the above prefixes appear

```
 *>  10.69.69.0/24    10.1.243.17 0 2856 12641 65299 i
 *>  10.69.114.0/23   10.1.243.17 0 2856 12641 65299 i
 *>  10.69.116.0/23   10.1.243.17 0 2856 12641 65299 i
 *>  10.69.120.0/24   10.1.243.17 0 2856 12641 65299 i
 *>  10.69.122.0/23   10.1.243.17 0 2856 12641 65299 i
```

So I tried to add the missing prefixes again, (just in case the router didn't include it) , but when I try and add 10.69.118.0/23 I get the message its already included, see below,

```
ip prefix-list allnet permit 10.69.109.0/24
**%Insertion failed - prefix-list entry exists:** 
   seq 475 permit 10.69.109.0/24
```

Can someone please tell me why the prefix won't appear in the BGP table even though its added?

Comment: Please add the BGP configuration and routing policies, al you show us is a filter, not how you're trying to add these prefixes to the routing table.

Comment: The short answer is the prefixes are not in the BGP table.

Comment: Thanks for responding. The BGP configuration is as follows:router bgp 65298
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 network 10.9.252.90 mask 255.255.255.255
 network 10.16.76.0 mask 255.255.255.0
 network 10.112.224.0 mask 255.255.254.0
 network 10.112.226.0 mask 255.255.254.0
 network 10.112.228.0 mask 255.255.254.0
 network 10.112.230.0 mask 255.255.254.0
 network 10.112.232.0 mask 255.255.255.0
 
 redistribute static
 neighbor 10.1.x.x remote-as 2856
 neighbor 10.1.x.x ebgp-multihop 3
 neighbor 10.1.x.x soft-reconfiguration inbound
 neighbor 10.1.x.x prefix-list allnet in

Comment: Is that what you need?

Comment: It doesn't make sense, as the prefix is in the list, but just won't populate the BGP table.

Comment: name#show ip prefix-list 
ip prefix-list admin: 0 entries
ip prefix-list adsvr: 0 entries
ip prefix-list allnet: 121 entries
  eq 440 permit 10.69.112.0/20
   seq 455 permit 10.69.116.0/23
   seq 460 permit 10.69.118.0/23
   seq 465 permit 10.69.108.0/22
   seq 470 permit 10.69.108.0/24
   seq 475 permit 10.69.109.0/24
   seq 480 permit 10.69.110.0/24
   seq 485 permit 10.69.111.0/24

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why the paste of the prefix lists won't appear as a table, to make it more legible.

Comment: Please edit your question instead of posting comments, so you can use markup.

Comment: Thanks for responding. The BGP configuration is as follows:router bgp 65298 bgp log-neighbor-changes network 10.9.252.90 mask 255.255.255.255 network 10.16.76.0 mask 255.255.255.0 network 10.112.224.0 mask 255.255.254.0 network 10.112.226.0 mask 255.255.254.0 network 10.112.228.0 mask 255.255.254.0 network 10.112.230.0 mask 255.255.254.0 network 10.112.232.0 mask 255.255.255.0 redistribute static neighbor 10.1.x.x remote-as 2856 neighbor 10.1.x.x ebgp-multihop 3 neighbor 10.1.x.x soft-reconfiguration inbound neighbor 10.1.x.x prefix-list allnet in

Comment: I'm not what you mean by 'edit your question instead of posting comment'. I thought to add additional remarks I needed to add a comment.

Comment: Do you mean, 'edit the original question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `ip prefix-list` does NOT insert prefixes into BGP route table.
That command is used to FILTER prefixes when the router announces or learns prefixes from BGP peers.

A common Cisco idiom for locally injecting prefixes into BGP is combining the BGP "network" statement with static routes to Null0:

```
router bgp <ASN>
 network 10.69.108.0 mask 255.255.255.0

ip route 10.69.108.0 255.255.255.0 Null0 250
```